# How to open DEV C++ IDE source code as a project?

Tags: c++, ide, dev-c++

The source code of the IDE is uploaded by at this [site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Source/)  but i do not know how to use.

I came from programming in using IDE like netbeans and visual studio where you can just open the project(the code), edit, then COMPILE. I want to do the same for the source code of the IDE DEV C++, how do i do this?

Comment: You want to open it in an IDE, I presume. What IDE is that?

Comment: yes, i want to open the source code of the [dev c++] in an IDE.. i do not know what type of IDE can do this (i.e. if it is possible)

Comment: Since the files have a *.pas extension, I assume you can open it in a Delphi or Turbo Pascal IDE.

Comment: Do you understand that an IDE itself is _also_ a program, albeit a complex one? Since you're asking about how to _use_ an IDE, I think you're a beginner. But beginners are unlikely to be able to work on the _source code_ of an IDE sicne that's so complex.

Comment: Yes @waka i have tried using Lazarus (pascal ide) to open the files one by one. But, what i want to do is to be able to open the project as a whole.. then compile. I am a beginner at this guys please bear with me

Comment: Try either the *.dof or the *.dpk file in Source/VCL.

Comment: @waka thank you, this definitely worked. how do i credit you for this? haha

Comment: @emineminems: I posted an answer. If it helped you, you can upvote and/or accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

1. After downloading and extracting the latest source, I looked into the *Source* folder
2. I noticed the *.pas file extension, since I did work with Delphi before I new it was either Turbo Pascal or Delphi (if you don't know the extensions, there are many great search engines who can tell you what kind of file you are looking at)
3. I opened the *README.txt* inside the *Source* folder, which tells me to compile *Source\VLC\DevCpp.dpk*. Again, I have worked with Delphi in the past, so I knew this is a project file (the extension means *Delphi Package Project*). *.dof is an older extension (Delphi 7 and older, the extension means *Delphi Project Options File*).

So, in short: Look at the file extensions and see if you can locate a README (or a similar named file) anywhere in the downloaded files. This should help you to figure out with what you are dealing and how you can open the project.